# How to call private REST endpoint from Azure Data Factory pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Context:

- I'm new to ADF
- I got a single resource group with multiple resources inside (relevant are data factory, web app and multiple databases).

  - All of them are inside same vnet
  - All of them have public access disabled
  - All of them have private endpoints created
  - vnet is part of bigger private networking setup and is peered to more vnets, but I don't think that's relevant here?

Issue:

When making HTTP request (using Web activity), it fails with that standard Azure's 403 page saying web app has blocked access, which is error when accessing the webapp outside of vnet.
That activity uses its own auto-resolve integration runtime that is connected to the same vnet.

How is this different from connecting to sql databases in same vnet that I already verified that it works?

Answer (score 0):

I would review the error logs from the ADF Web activity for more specific error details, also if possible will test the connectivity using a VM within the same VNet to simulate the ADF's access to the web app and make sure that the private endpoints for web app are correctly configured and linked to the VNet. Another thing is to ensure that the DNS settings within the VNet resolve the private endpoint of the web app correctly.